# Array size based on the file being read

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to base my array size on the amount of lines being read from a text file, which has an unknown amount of lines. I've tried to read the file twice, with the first time going through with a while loop and incrementing an int and then use that for the array size but that didn't seem to work. I then tried to put the values of the lines into a list and get the list size but that also didn't work. Any help would be great.

First time using an int to increment. I get nothing returned.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Scan {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String routeName = " ";
    String stationName = " ";
    Scanner timetable = new Scanner(new File("fileName.txt"));
    int i = 0;
    while(timetable.hasNext()){ 
    i++;
    }
    int count = 0;
    String [] s = new String[i];
    while (timetable.hasNext()) {
        String line = timetable.nextLine();
        s[count++] = line;      
    }
    routeName = s[0];
    stationName = s[1];
    System.out.println(routeName.toString());
    System.out.println(stationName.toString());         
}

}
```

Second time using a list. I get a NullPointerException.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Scan {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String routeName = " ";
    String stationName = " ";
    Scanner timetable = new Scanner(new File("fileName.txt"));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(timetable.hasNext()){ 
    list.add(timetable.next);
    }
    int i = list.size(); 
    int count = 0;
    String [] s = new String[i];
    while (timetable.hasNext()) {
        String line = timetable.nextLine();
        s[count++] = line;      
    }
    routeName = s[0];
    stationName = s[1];
    System.out.println(routeName.toString());
    System.out.println(stationName.toString());         
}

}
```

Comment: Do you need to use an array? Why not use `List`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "path";


        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
                    Charset.defaultCharset());
            for (String line : lines) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Though instead of array it will store in List. But will work for your purpose. Note that it works for java 7.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it is better to use a List. But besides that, there is a bug in your code. You must reset your timetable variable again before the second while statement.

Hope this helps.